# Wizard based feature activation in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2010

I was wondering if SharePoint 2010 has wizard based feature activation, let me explain.

Lets say I have a list definition in the feature.

During feature activation I would like to present a web form that asks "How many lists do you want to create?"

The user then selects a number for example 5.

Now the feature will create 5 new list instances.

I know this type of thing was definitely not possible with SharePoint 2007, so can 2010 cater for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For achieving this you can create a custom application page and host it in your central administration. Further through the object model, you can activate and provide a dropdown target your feature for a specific web application/site collection.

Further in the same application page (optionally you can add another and link to the first one) you can add the required logic to create list instance once your feature gets activates.

The same approach is valid for both MOSS and SP2010.

Comment: Sounds good, but I'm not sure if installing a custom application / section in a customers central administration is the correct approach. It is a solution, so I thank you for mentioning it, but I think we both can agree its a tacky workaround because SharePoint doesn't do stuff like this OOB.

Comment: Agreed. The reason i mentioned CA was if you need to target the same feature/functionality to multiple web apps on the farm then doing it via a common place like CA can be an approach.
If we know that the feature/functionality is for a specific app, then doing the same in Site Collection is an option.
Other than this I dont think we can have a wizard based feature installation using a web form.